# Chart by amCharts shows no bestFitLine

Tags: javascript, amcharts

So, I just wanted to create a chart by amCharts with 3 graphs, which should show all a best fit line. There's a plugin you can download for that. All done.

After integrating it into my code, it would generate the chart with the 3 graphs, but no best fit line. Here's a code snipped I integrated:

```
"bestFitLine": {
    "lineColor": "#EC7A2C",
    "lineAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "title": "Linear (Gesamt)"
}
```

I uploaded an example of my code into codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVXeVj

The example code is half made out of my own code and half out of the example code that was assigned to the best fit line plugin:
http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/8bf741f6fc8c6c330ee317baa2bc1dee

I really can't see where the problem is...

EDIT: Just figured that there seems to be a problem with my dataset. The plugin has problems with values containing decimals. I don't wanna round all values. Is there maybe a workaround possible?

Comment: Change your values. Put numbers instead of string : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObgXLG

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had to figure that myself, but... well, sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees.